# Transfer large file app service deployment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have a system that will require access to a large file (600MB)

Am I right in thinking that I would therefore need to use a VM in Azure?  Is there a way of getting single files into an App service system?

I can see this taking a very long time to deploy!

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not necessarily need to have a VM just to store and access that file, but should rather consider using Azure Files instead which is a cost effective solution and matches your use case. Here is a brief explanation of its capabilities:

Replace or supplement on-premises file servers:

Azure Files can be used to completely replace or supplement traditional on-premises file servers or NAS devices. Popular operating systems such as Windows, macOS, and Linux can directly mount Azure File shares wherever they are in the world. Azure File shares can also be replicated with Azure File Sync to Windows Servers, either on-premises or in the cloud, for performant and distributed caching of the data where it's being used.

**"Lift and shift" applications:**
Azure Files makes it easy to "lift and shift" applications to the cloud that expect a file share to store file application or user data. Azure Files enables both the "classic" lift and shift scenario, where both the application and it's data are moved to Azure, and the "hybrid" lift and shift scenario, where the application data is moved to Azure Files, and the application continues to run on-premises.

Simplify cloud development:
Azure Files can also be used in numerous ways to simplify new cloud development projects. For example:
Shared application settings:
A common pattern for distributed applications is to have configuration files in a centralized location where they can be accessed from many application instances. Application instances can load their configuration through the File REST API, and humans can access them as needed by mounting the SMB share locally.

Diagnostic share:
An Azure File share is a convenient place for cloud applications to their write logs, metrics, and crash dumps. Logs can be written by the application instances via the File REST API, and developers can access them by mounting the file share on their local machine. This enables great flexibility, as developers can embrace cloud development without having to abandon any existing tooling they know and love.
Dev/Test/Debug:
When developers or administrators are working on VMs in the cloud, they often need a set of tools or utilities. Copying such utilities and tools to each VM can be a time consuming exercise. By mounting an Azure File share locally on the VMs, a developer and administrator can quickly access their tools and utilities, no copying required.

For the full use cases of Azure files, please checkout this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction#why-azure-files-is-useful

Comment: This looks very good!  However I am a bit confused about using this instead of app services?  Azure files seems to be a container so how would I get azure to actually host my system for use by my users?

Comment: ah! I was under the impression that accessing and hosting the file alone was the concern. If it is a system, I'd recommend checking out Azure App services : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/ , there is a Free trial option which provides 1GB of disk space, I'd suggest giving it a try to see if it suits your use case, otherwise having a VM would also be another option.

Comment: I already have app services I have concerns about how to get a 600MB file up there!

Comment: Paul, are you concerned about the time required to upload the file from your premises to the cloud, or time taken to handle the file _after_ its in Azure?   I think the latter is probably best approached as Adam suggested - just try it.  Your file size is well within the bounds of the free trial app service tier.

As for uploading the file, if you put it into Azure files (or _possibly_ Azure blob storage), you should only have to upload it once, and then the app can access it from there. You can upload it with AzCopy which should give you decent performance for a file of that size.

Comment: Its getting the file into the app service itself and as there is no actual file system in app services am a bit confused about how to reference it.  I am marking this as an answer though because it does answer how to get a large file up to Azure

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused by your mention of "a long time to deploy" but... no, a Virtual Machine is *not* required, to have an environment with storage.

Azure Web Apps have built-in storage of their own. At the "Basic" tier, you have 10GB at your disposal (and it grows upwards of 1TB as you scale up in tier). And that storage is *durable* (until you delete the web app itself) and shared across all running instances of the web app.

You may also store content in Azure Blob Storage.  And if/as you need to work with this content locally, you can download blob content to your local (web app) storage via SDK/API calls. Assuming the Storage account and Web App are in the same region, there will be no bandwidth costs copying between the two.

Azure File Storage works as well, but has limitations:
 - 5TB max per storage instance
 - Max 1000 IOPS across entire storage instance
 - Cannot be SMB-attached to a Web App - you need to access it programmatically (via SDK/API)

Note: As long as you keep your large content (such as your 600MB file) in blob/file storage, you don't have to include it in your web app every time you deploy; you can copy it down to your web app's storage upon startup.